# QtDesigner preview different from the actual GUI

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt, pyqt5, qt-designer

Python 3.4, PyQt5, QtDesigner

I made a GUI using QtDesigner but the python application GUI produced from it does not match the preview shown by QtDesigner. It seems like the problem has to do with the dimensions/spacing of my grid layouts. I did not manually edit anything in the GUI, all of the code was created by QtDesigner.

QtDesigner preview and application GUI:

[image]

QtDesigner .ui file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>800</width>
    <height>600</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <widget class="QGroupBox" name="groupBox">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>30</x>
      <y>20</y>
      <width>131</width>
      <height>111</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="title">
     <string>GroupBox</string>
    </property>
    <widget class="QWidget" name="gridLayoutWidget">
     <property name="geometry">
      <rect>
       <x>10</x>
       <y>20</y>
       <width>111</width>
       <height>81</height>
      </rect>
     </property>
     <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout">
      <property name="spacing">
       <number>5</number>
      </property>
      <item row="1" column="0">
       <widget class="QLabel" name="label">
        <property name="text">
         <string>a =</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item row="1" column="3">
       <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit_3"/>
      </item>
      <item row="2" column="2">
       <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit_5"/>
      </item>
      <item row="2" column="1">
       <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit_4"/>
      </item>
      <item row="1" column="1">
       <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit"/>
      </item>
      <item row="3" column="3">
       <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit_9"/>
      </item>
      <item row="3" column="1">
       <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit_7"/>
      </item>
      <item row="2" column="0">
       <widget class="QLabel" name="label_2">
        <property name="text">
         <string>b =</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item row="2" column="3">
       <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit_6"/>
      </item>
      <item row="1" column="2">
       <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit_2"/>
      </item>
      <item row="3" column="0">
       <widget class="QLabel" name="label_3">
        <property name="text">
         <string>c =</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item row="3" column="2">
       <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit_8"/>
      </item>
      <item row="0" column="1" colspan="3">
       <widget class="QLabel" name="label_4">
        <property name="text">
         <string>(   x  ,    y   ,   z   )</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
     </layout>
    </widget>
   </widget>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>800</width>
     <height>21</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

The .ui file was converted to testGUI.py using pyuic.

This is the application code:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from testGUI import Ui_MainWindow

class App(Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, dialog):
        Ui_MainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(dialog)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    dialog = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()

    testGUI = App(dialog)

    dialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE] (emphasis on *minimal*).

Comment: @Mailerdaimon Added a minimal example. Replaced .py file with .ui file.

Comment: @zdub. Neither the group-box nor the main-window has a layout, so it's hard to guess what behaviour you expect from this example. When I view it in Qt Designer, it does not look like either of your screenshots. If you don't use layouts in a consistent way, the results will be strictly undefined.

Comment: What is it that you want? A UI that is working and that is resizeable or a UI that looks exactly like in the designer without resizing. The normal approach in Qt is to use Layouts. Layouts make sure that your UI works even when resizing or changing the aspect ratio but the widgets may change their size for this to work. The other approach would be to set a fixed size for every UI element. I would not recommend to do this! Read more about Qt Layout System [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/layout.html).

Comment: @Mailerdaimon well why they create designer in the first place if the outcome gonna be different anyway?. it happens to me also. the preview is different than the freshly converted python version

Comment: @lone_coder because that is not the point of the designer, it cannot show you a precise preview for a flexible UI as the UI is, well, flexible. If everything is fixed and the designer output still does not fit file a bugreport and ask the qt maintainers.

Answer (score 2):

When I originally created the GUI, I first added a grid layout widget `QGridLayout`, then filled it with items, then dragged it over and placed it within the group box container `QGroupBox`.

I solved the problem by not using a `QGridLayout` at all and instead simply adding the items to `QGroupBox` then applying the grid layout to the container. The application GUI now matches the QtDesigner preview.

Comment: sadly. my UI depends on the grid. so this can't be my answer (I had the same question as you did). and I already adding items in QGroupBox with zero luck